# Why `run, explore` doesn't work with expression syntax?

Tags: autohotkey

Why `run, explore` doesn't work with expression syntax?

Any ideas? Big thanks in advance.

```
dir := "C:\Users\"

; Works
run explore %dir%

; Doesn't work. Why?
run explore % dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This demonstrates run using expression syntax:**

```
run % "explorer " dir
```

Comment: Hm. For me, the result is not the same: sidebar isn't shown. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/lmyBzW1.png. Probably on your PC it works differently?

Comment: Well, it should be `run % "explore " dir` (not `explorer`). And with this fix, everything works fine!

Comment: Ah.  I assumed you were launching `c:\windows\explorer.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Because the percent-space prefix for forcing an expression must be used at the beginning of any parameter and nowhere else.

To the `Run` command, `explore %dir%` or `explore % dir` is just a single parameter, where you can't put the prefix in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

In DOS batch file this is the way to access variables - `%VARIABLE_NAME%`
So `%dir%` is a valid variable that has values defined in your script, while `%` and `dir` with a space in between does not reference to `dir` you have defined.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/121170/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-an-ms-dos-batch-file]